# Error compiling a custom container for boost spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I want to parse something like the following:

```
1;2
=1200
3;4
5;6
```

lines can appear in any order. Lines starting with the = sign can be more than one and only the last one matters; lines containing a ; represent a pair of values that I want to store in a map. Reading the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158376/getting-boostspiritqi-to-use-stl-containers) I came up with some code that should be good enough (sorry but I'm still a noob with Spirit) and should do what I'm trying to achieve. Here's the code:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#define DATAPAIR_PAIR

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/bool.hpp>
#include <map>
#if !defined(DATAPAIR_PAIR)
#include <vector>
#endif


static const char g_data[] = "1;2\n=1200\n3;4\n5;6\n";
typedef std::string DataTypeFirst;

#if defined(DATAPAIR_PAIR)
typedef std::string DataTypeSecond;
typedef std::pair<DataTypeFirst, DataTypeSecond> DataPair;
typedef std::map<DataTypeFirst, DataTypeSecond> DataMap;
#else
typedef std::vector<DataTypeFirst> DataPair;
typedef std::map<DataTypeFirst, DataTypeFirst> DataMap;
#endif

struct MyContainer {
    DataMap data;
    double number;
};

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template<> struct is_container<MyContainer> : boost::mpl::true_ {};

    template<>
    struct container_value<MyContainer> {
        typedef boost::variant<double, DataPair> type;
    };

    template <>
    struct push_back_container<MyContainer, double> {
        static bool call ( MyContainer& parContainer, double parValue ) {
            parContainer.number = parValue;
            return true;
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct push_back_container<MyContainer, DataPair> {
        static bool call ( MyContainer& parContainer, const DataPair& parValue ) {
#if defined(DATAPAIR_PAIR)
            parContainer.data[parValue.first] = parValue.second;
#else
            parContainer.data[parValue[0]] = parValue[1];
#endif
            return true;
        }
    };
} } }

template <typename Iterator>
struct TestGrammar : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, MyContainer()> {

    TestGrammar ( void );
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, MyContainer()> start;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, DataPair()> data;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, double()> num;
};

template <typename Iterator>
TestGrammar<Iterator>::TestGrammar() :
    TestGrammar::base_type(start)
{
    using boost::spirit::qi::alnum;
    using boost::spirit::qi::lit;
    using boost::spirit::ascii::char_;;
    using boost::spirit::qi::double_;
    using boost::spirit::qi::eol;
    using boost::spirit::qi::eoi;

    start %= *((num | data) >> (eol | eoi));
    data = +alnum >> lit(";") >> +alnum;
    num = '=' >> double_;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Parsing data:\n" << g_data << "\n";

    TestGrammar<const char*> gramm;
    MyContainer result;
    boost::spirit::qi::parse(static_cast<const char*>(g_data),
        g_data + sizeof(g_data) / sizeof(g_data[0]) - 1,
        gramm,
        result
    );
    std::cout << "Parsed data:\n";
    std::cout << "Result: " << result.number << "\n";
    for (const auto& p : result.data) {
        std::cout << p.first << " = " << p.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm developing this on Gentoo Linux, using dev-libs/boost-1.55.0-r2:0/1.55.0 and gcc (Gentoo 4.8.3 p1.1, pie-0.5.9) 4.8.3. Compiling the above code I get an error like

/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:278:13: error: ‘struct MyContainer’ has no member named ‘insert’

as a workaround, I came up with the alternative code you get by commenting the "#define DATAPAIR_PAIR" line. In that case the code compiles and works, but what I really want is a pair where I can for example mix std::string and int values. Why using std::pair as the attribute for my data rule causes the compiler to miss the correct specialization of push_back_container? Is it possible to fix the code and have it working, either using std::pair or anything equivalent?

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81459094d3aed670) works, but is far from pretty. The only addition is marked with a `//ADDED`. Sadly I don't know why it is needed in your case and not in the example linked or your workaround.

Comment: @cv_and_he what a timing

Comment: @cv_and_he that's a pretty strange requirement (actually, it makes sense, but it's strange in the sense that it isn't always required). Nice work though. I couldn't get it to work, so cheated by looking at your solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simplify this by /just/ not treating things like a container and not-a-container at the same time. So for this particular situation I might deviate from my usual mantra ([avoid semantic actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)) and use them¹:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f09220e5b942a3dc)</kbd>**

```
template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::blank_type>
struct grammar : qi::grammar<It, MyContainer(), Skipper> {
    grammar() : grammar::base_type(start) {
        update_number = '=' > qi::double_ [ qi::_r1 = qi::_1 ];
        map_entry     = qi::int_ > ';' > qi::int_;

        auto number = phx::bind(&MyContainer::number, qi::_val);
        auto data   = phx::bind(&MyContainer::data, qi::_val);

        start         = *(
            (   update_number(number) 
              | map_entry [ phx::insert(data, phx::end(data), qi::_1) ]
            )
            >> qi::eol);
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, void(double&),       Skipper> update_number;
    qi::rule<It, MyContainer::Pair(), Skipper> map_entry;
    qi::rule<It, MyContainer(),       Skipper> start;
};
```

If you can afford a `(0;0)` entry in your map, you can even dispense with the grammar:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/205b55f8b9c3e039)</kbd>**

```
std::map<int, int> data;
double number;

bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, 
       *(
            (qi::omit['=' > qi::double_ [phx::ref(number)=qi::_1]] 
          | (qi::int_ > ';' > qi::int_)
        ) >> qi::eol)
        , qi::blank, data);
```

I can try to make your "advanced spirit" approach work too, but it might take a while :)

---

¹ <sub>I use `auto` for readability, but of course you don't need to use that; just repeat the subexpressions inline or use BOOST_AUTO. Note that this is not generically good advice for stateful parser expressions (see BOOST_SPIRIT_AUTO)</sub>

Comment: This is probably a better (saner?) solution.

Comment: Either this, or I'd just bite the bullet and parse what the input is, and _then_ interpret that to find the last value of the `number` field

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. So to make my question more specific, I'm trying to implement a cuesheet parser as an excercise (as in .cue/.bin, see "cue sheet" on wikipedia). The eterogenous part in that case is "FILE <name> <type>", where I store name/type as string/enum, but I also had issues with the case string/string. In a case like cuesheet what's the best approach? Semantic actions as sehe suggested or visitors or 2-pass parsing as cv_and_he suggested?

Comment: I'd just read the file as is. Cue sheets are not huge and you can afford to just represent the redundant information in memory. Heck, it might even help you detect the many quirks that certain media players/organizers have developed in their particular implementations of this "standard" format. This way, you get the simplest possible parser, no traits hell, no semantic actions ***and*** the richest possible data representation.