# Parsing using boost Spirit into STL vector

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, stdvector, boost-spirit

I'm learning Boost Spirit 2, and I can't figure out why I can't parse a sequence of two integers into an STL vector of int. From the documentation of the >> operator ([here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/sequence.html#spirit.qi.reference.operator.sequence.attributes)) I know the attribute of the grammar `int_ >> int_` should be `vector<int>`. And from the [attribute notation documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html#spirit.qi.quick_reference.compound_attribute_rules.notation) I know that "The notation of `vector<A>` stands for *any STL container* holding elements of type A".

And yet, when I try to add an action to `int_ >> int_`, which takes `std::vector` as its attribute, compilation fails.

Among other error messages, it says: `/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:163:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘boost::fusion::vector<int, int>’ to ‘const std::vector<int>&’`

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158376/getting-boostspiritqi-to-use-stl-containers) ("Getting boost::spirit::qi to use stl containers"), but the solution there - including std_tuple.hpp - did not change anything.

Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

namespace client
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    class ParserActions
    {
    public:
        void printivec (std::vector<int> const& ivec)
        {
            std::cout << "We see " << ivec.size() << " integers" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_ivec(Iterator first, Iterator last)
    {
        using ascii::space;

        ParserActions actionContainer;

        auto two_ints = (qi::int_ >> qi::int_);

        bool r = qi::parse(
            first,                          /*< start iterator >*/
            last,                           /*< end iterator >*/
            two_ints[boost::bind(&ParserActions::printivec,&actionContainer,_1)]
            );

        return first == last && r;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "12 13";

    if (client::parse_ivec(str.begin(),str.end()))
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parsing failed!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int_ >> int_` synthesizes a tuple of int, int.¹

If you want to force synthesizing a container, make it `repeat(2) [ int_ ]` to express that.

> **Sidenote**: As you'll see below, there's room for attribute compatibility even if the bound attribute is a cotainer, so you don't need to.

> **Sidenote**: `auto` with parser expressions is asking undefined behaviour: [Assigning parsers to auto variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables/22027181#22027181)

> **Sidenote**: your input uses space delimiter, but the parser doesn't. That will never work.

Your code sample seems to have little to do with the goal, so here's my small example:

### 1. `vector<int>`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f487f66090e4bc01)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
using Vec = std::vector<int>;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It> Vec parse_ivec(It first, It last) {
    Vec v;
    if (qi::phrase_parse(first, last,  qi::int_ >> qi::int_ >> qi::eoi, qi::space, v))
        return v;
    throw std::runtime_error("Parse failed");
}

Vec parse_ivec(std::string const& r) { return parse_ivec(begin(r), end(r)); }

int main() {
    for (int i : parse_ivec("12 13")) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
12
13
```

### 2. Adapted structs

Alternatively, if you wanted a struct, not `std::vector<>`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6203dfddb8f28017)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
struct Vec { int a, b; };
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Vec, a, b)

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It> Vec parse_ivec(It first, It last) {
    Vec v;
    if (qi::phrase_parse(first, last,  qi::int_ >> qi::int_ >> qi::eoi, qi::space, v))
        return v;
    throw std::runtime_error("Parse failed");
}

Vec parse_ivec(std::string const& r) { return parse_ivec(begin(r), end(r)); }

int main() {
    Vec vec = parse_ivec("12 13");
    std::cout << vec.a << " " << vec.b << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
12 13
```

### 3. `std::tuple<int, int>`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58fdfb741c25adbd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
using Vec = std::tuple<int, int>;

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It> Vec parse_ivec(It first, It last) {
    Vec v;
    if (qi::phrase_parse(first, last,  qi::int_ >> qi::int_ >> qi::eoi, qi::space, v))
        return v;
    throw std::runtime_error("Parse failed");
}

Vec parse_ivec(std::string const& r) { return parse_ivec(begin(r), end(r)); }

int main() {
    Vec vec = parse_ivec("12 13");
    std::cout << std::get<0>(vec) << " " << std::get<1>(vec) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
12 13
```

---

¹ Technically, a Fusion sequence, which can be made compatible with a host of types like std::pair, or your own types adapted.

Comment: Thank you! These work (of course). The first example is what I was trying to achieve, but I do want to have several rules and actions associated with them. I will experiment a bit more...

Comment: Yup. You're welcome with other questions down the road