# Position annotation for sequences in Spirit X3

Tags: boost-spirit-x3

What is considered good form for adding position annotations for rules that return sequences?

Assuming I have a rule in my grammar of the form:

```
const auto array_def = '[' >> *int_ >> ']';
```

that synthesizes an attribute of type `std::vector< int >`, I thought about adding position annotation via an encapsulation of the vector sequence into a made-up type:

```
struct array_t { std::vector< int > value; };
```

and add position annotation as per the X3 tutorials:

```
struct array_t : x3::position_tagged { std::vector< int > value; };
```

, etc. Unfortunately, this does not work as explained in [Boost.Spirit X3 parser "no type named type in(...)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252680/boost-spirit-x3-parser-no-type-named-type-in) where I see that collapsing single element sequences has been rejected in Spirit.

What's left is perhaps to go the route of:

```
struct array_t : x3::position_tagged, std::vector< int > { };
```

which would work (actually, works) but it contradicts decades of good practice that says don't inherit `std` types. What is good X3 form here?

Comment: 1) If you want your type to be treated as a container - implement container API for it. 2) Using `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` on a type makes the type a Fusion **sequence** (check with [`is_sequence` trait](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/support/is_sequence.html)) and has an implication for Spirit. 3) There is nothing wrong with inheriting `std::vector` and your case is a perfect example of a situation when it is justified.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If you create an answer I will mark it answered.